# Curl Bash check Path

Tags: bash, shell, curl, url, request

Firstly I want to thank for commenting nicely, And
Sorry my question was not clear enough, I wanted to know if it is possible to fuzz a path in a list of URLs, if I have a list of URLs, the URLs is unknown to me but I want to Fuzz any part of the URL, suppose,

```
https://example.com/something/hello.html
https://example.com/nothing/welcome.php
https://example.com/something/nothing
```

I want to Fuzz any part of those URLS
Suppose the middle part, as like,

```
https://example.com/nothing/welcome.php
```

After appending string in "nothing" the path will be like,

```
https://example.com/mystring/welcome.php
```

If there is a long URL like

```
https://example.com/nothing/welcome/hello.html
```

I want to Fuzz "welcome" with any keywords.

So it will be like

```
https://example.com/nothing/mystring/hello.html
```

So using Curl can I Fuzz any path? to Fuzz any path of the URLS

Tried:

```
echo "https://example.com/1/hello.html" | while read url; do test=$(curl -s $url/3\' | grep '3'); test2=$(curl -s $url/6 | grep '6'); echo -e "$url""\n""[line 1] $url/test""\n""[line 2] $url/?$test";done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `func(){ url=$1; test=$( ... ; } for ((n=1;n<=10;n++)); do func "https.../$n/..."; done`

Comment: `https://example.com/[1-10]/hello.html`

Comment: @Jetchisel Do you mean: `https://example.com/{1..10}/hello.html` ?

Comment: How can I Fuzz any part of the URLs, like append something in the middle of the URL, using Curl can I do it?

Comment: `curl` can just fetch URLs. Any scripting language with string processing facilities will let you manipulate a set of URL strings to pass to `curl`. Bash is certainly one, though its facilities are rather basic; perhaps look at e.g. Python for more versatile fuzzing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking but this is probably what you want

```
for n in {1..10}; do printf 'https://example.com/%d/hello.html\n' "$n"; done | xargs -n 1 curl -s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -I% echo curl http://foo.bar/%/chese
curl http://foo.bar/1/chese
curl http://foo.bar/2/chese
curl http://foo.bar/3/chese
curl http://foo.bar/4/chese
curl http://foo.bar/5/chese
curl http://foo.bar/6/chese
curl http://foo.bar/7/chese
curl http://foo.bar/8/chese
curl http://foo.bar/9/chese
```

This solution depends on gnu xargs (findutils).

-I% means replace each argument (substitute % with argument) in the final command. % is an arbitrary char.

for examgle, {} works too.

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs  -I {} echo curl http://foo.bar/%/{}/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/1/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/2/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/3/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/4/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/5/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/6/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/7/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/8/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/9/chese
curl http://foo.bar/%/10/chese
```